# Objective-C: Call Class Method of Subclass

Tags: objective-c, subclass, superclass, class-method

Let's say I have an Objective-C class called MyBaseClass and a subclass called MySubclassedClass.

The MyBaseClass has two class methods:

```
+ (UIColor *)backgroundColor;
+ (UIImage *)backgroundImage;
```

The backgroundColor method calls `backgroundImage`. If it was confined to MyBaseClass, my `backgroundColor` method would look like

```
+ (UIColor *)backgroundColor {
     UIImage *img = [MyBaseClass backgroundImage];
     // irrelevant
     return color;
}
```

But I want to be able to subclass MyBaseClass to MySubclassedClass. `backgroundColor` would not change and always call the parent's `backgroundImage` method. In this scenario, `backgroundImage` would be overridden in every subclass.

If 1backgroundColor1 was an instance method, I would simply use

```
UIImage *img = [[self class] backgroundImage];
```

but, there is no 'self' I can use when it's a static method.

Is there some away I can accomplish this in Objective-C?

Comment: And why do you think that there is no self in methods of class?

Comment: I replaced the word "static methods" with "class methods". Class methods in Objective-C are `virtual` in the C++ sense, not `static`...  I think this choice of terminology in C++ was unfortunate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you send a message to a class method from another class method, self is the class. Therefore, you can do the following:

```
UIImage *img = [self backgroundImage];
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize self referred to the class.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `self` inside of a class (static) method.  In this case, `self` refers to the class object.